# Angular selection display default value for a null ng-model value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

The select list below is display empty row instead of the default value `"--Weight--"` when `product.weightUnitMeasureCode` is null.

```
<select ng-model="product.weightUnitMeasureCode">
    <option value="">-- Weight --</option>
    <option ng-repeat="unitMeasure in unitMeasures |filter:unitMeasure.isSize='false'" value="{{unitMeasure.unitMeasureCode}}">{{unitMeasure.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to make the list display the default option when `product.weightUnitMeasureCode` is null? I've tried changing the value of the default option to the following but it didn't work.

```
value="null"
value=null
```

Comment: use `ng-option` instead of `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are in wrong direction as far as [angular version of select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) has been concerned.

Try:-

```
<select ng-model="product.weightUnitMeasureCode" 
        ng-options="unitMeasure.code as unitMeasure.name for unitMeasure in unitMeasures | filter:unitMeasure.isSize==false">
   <option value="">-- Weight --</option>
</select>
```

<sup>I am not sure if you have a field called code in your data model, but you can adjust based on your model.</sup>

if you want to filter out ones with `unitMeasure.isSize` on a static list then you should just filter them at the controller itself and bind only the required list.